# Is correct to say $H\times K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and its order is $q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let $G\cong \mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_m$.

If I proved $H\times K$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}_n\times \mathbb{Z}_m$ and $|H\times K|=q$,

is correct to say $H\times K$ is a subgroup of $G$ and its order is $q$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, not exactly, since the (underlying set of) each subgroup of $G$ is a subset of (the underlying set of) $G$.

The best you can say is that $H\times K$ is *isomorphic* to a subgroup of $G$.

Isomorphisms preserve order.

All this is true regardless of what $G,H,K$ are.

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: You're welcome, @JhonKnows.